# ASP.NET Web Api - Error while controller scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to run simple ASP.NET Web API project (.NET Framework 4.5.2). It is using class library which is stored in .dll file. While adding controller using "API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework" I got this error:

`A type with the name [A].[B] does not exist`

`in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   in Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)`

Where `A` is my CL's main namespace and `B` is class which I wanted to make controller from.

What's the solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you build the solution before you tried to scaffold? also did you add a reference to the class library that has your class in your web project?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not really answer to this question, but I changed from including class library as dll to including entire class library project and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn't like mixed/minor versions between project references AND referenced project references.

Because My Domain and Data classes live in separate projects needed to synced those references up to 5.0.2. and from the Web.Api project removed all the reference that were already included in those library projects.

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" PrivateAssets="All" />

      <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="3.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle" Version="5.6.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Before I figured that out my work around was to use the cli

> dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator controller -name CustomerController -api -m Customer -dc AccountContextApi -outDir Controllers